# ASP.NET Textbox Mask

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, textbox, mask

So I want to include a mask to my textbox. I have researched for different options and I have tried all of them but none seem to work. Im using VS2013 and C# and I want to be able to use textbox.text on my code too.

I have something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#TxtDOB").mask("999-999-9999");
        });
    </script>

asp:TextBox ID="TxtDOB" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1" Width="130px" />
```

TextBox won't recognize the mask.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Is the textbox added to the page dynamically (after the initial page load)?

Comment: Correct. It is a field that gets populated first and it also serves as an adding new dob

Comment: You'll have to initialize the mask plugin after the textbox is loaded. Right now it attempts to initialize to a non-existent element.

Comment: Jasen... I didn't it matter but I have tried already and it won't work

Comment: Check the rendered html. Does your textbox have `id="TxtDOB"`? Try `console.log($("#TxtDOB").length)` right before you call `.mask()` do you get the value `1`?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TxtDOB" runat="server" CssClass="textbox1" Width="130px" />

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but adding `ClientIDMode="static"` should fix the issue here. By default, .Net will convert the ID ("TxtDOB" in this case) to something other than what you set it to. Adding `ClientIDMode="static"` tells .Net not to change the ID and make it available as-is on the client-side.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtDOB" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" CssClass="textbox1" Width="130px" />
```